# Why are two classes in the same directory being imported differently in this Vue.js code?

Tags: vue.js

I'm working my way through the code of a Vue.js project.

In the file `src/model/TextSegment.js` the first two lines are:

```
import UniqueObject from "./UniqueObject";
import { TimeCode } from "@/model";
```

The file `UniqueObject.js` is a class file in the same directory, and so I understand that the `./` simply means the same directory and loads this file for use in `TextSegment.js` which extends this class.

But the file `TimeCode.js` is also a class in the same directory, albeit one that is instantiated, but I would expect it to be loaded with the same syntax, e.g.:

```
import TimeCode from "./TimeCode";
```

1. Why is `TimeCode` in squiggly brackets?
2. Why does it have a `@` instead of a `.` as a directory?

### src/model/UniqueObject.js

```
import uuidv4 from "uuid/v4";

class UniqueObject {
  constructor(initial = {}) {
    if (this.constructor == UniqueObject) {
      throw TypeError("Cannot instantiate abstract class UniqueObject");
    }
    this.uuid = initial.uuid || uuidv4();
  }
}

export default UniqueObject;
```

### src/model/TimeCode.js

```
class TimeCode {
  constructor(initials = {}) {
    this.seconds = initials.seconds || null;
    this.frame = initials.frame || null;
  }
}

export default TimeCode;
```

### src/model/TextSegment.js

```
import UniqueObject from "./UniqueObject";
import { TimeCode } from "@/model";

class TextSegment extends UniqueObject {
  constructor(initials = {}) {
    super(initials);
    this.content = initials.content || "";
    this.translation = initials.translation || "";
    this.notes = initials.notes || "";
    this.timecode_start = new TimeCode(initials.timecode_start || {});
    this.timecode_end = new TimeCode(initials.timecode_end || {});
    this.voice_id = initials.voice_id || null;
    this.filename = initials.filename || "";
  }
}

export default TextSegment;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of importing in JavaScript. These are the two most common ones.

`import UniqueObject from "./UniqueObject";` imports the default export variable. If you open the *UniqueObject* file you would most likely see something like `export default <var>`.

`import { TimeCode } from "@/model";` imports the `TimeCode` variable in the file at *@/model*. If you open the *model* file you would see something like `export const TimeCode`.

The `@` has to do with your module loader and depends on which module loader you use.

Comment: But `model` is the directory in which all of these files are contained. There is no file named `model`. There is however a file named `TimeCode`, in it a class named TimeCode, and after that the line `export default TimeCode`, but this is exact same format as the file `UniqueObject` has so I would expect both classes to be loaded similarly.

Comment: I posted the contents of `UniqueOjbect.js` and `TimeCode.js` above in the post.

Comment: Then you have to find out which module loader you're using and dig through their documentation as this is where you'll find the answer. Most advanced JS apps use module loader libs as JS is not natively good at this.

Comment: The `import UniqueOjbect` part simply tells the transpiler to import everything and `import { TimeCode }` only imports the _TimeCode_ var in the file.

Comment: I find `"vue-loader": "^12.1.0"` in my package.json. Can I assume that this is the only vue-loader that is being used?

Comment: If you haven't specifically implemented others, then yes, vue-loader should be the one you use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155309/discussion-between-d00dle-and-edward-tanguay).

Comment: When you import from a directory, typically the module loader will look for an `index.js` file in that directory and import from that.